# lua_getglobal triggered "attempt to index a thread value" error

Tags: lua, lua-api

I have completely no idea on how it could raise this error: even if the global does not exist, isn't it should give a nil?

Nevertheless, something I could ensure are:

- it is a valid `lua_State`;
- it is the main context, not a thread;
- the named global has been set previously, on the same `lua_State` instance.
- I never unset the global (as I don't know how to do that).

And this is the stack trace when error is raised:

```
    ZTD3UI.exe!luaD_throw(lua_State * L, int errcode) line 135  C++
    ZTD3UI.exe!luaG_errormsg(lua_State * L) line 775    C++
    ZTD3UI.exe!luaG_runerror(lua_State * L, const char * fmt, ...) line 789 C++
    ZTD3UI.exe!luaG_typeerror(lua_State * L, const TValue * o, const char * op) line 695    C++
    ZTD3UI.exe!luaV_finishget(lua_State * L, const TValue * t, TValue * key, StackValue * val, const TValue * slot) line 298    C++
    ZTD3UI.exe!auxgetstr(lua_State * L, const TValue * t, const char * k) line 646  C++
    ZTD3UI.exe!lua_getglobal(lua_State * L, const char * name) line 665 C++
```

Comment: How to reproduce this error?  Please post the code.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff The whole thing is too long. If the error message is not enough, I'll try to create a minimum scene.

Comment: You can try to run your program in a Lua built with `LUA_USE_APICHECK`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I added this macro, it reports the actual error which is a Lua stack overflow and I fixed it. Thanks for a lot!